# unable to start webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix

I recently installed WebMatrix. When I start the WebMatrix on my machine, it shows me the error and closes. Following are the error details

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: webmatrix.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 7.9.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4e694933
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core
  Problem Signature 05: 7.9.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4e69493b
  Problem Signature 07: 1544
  Problem Signature 08: 24
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

hi Justin Thanks for the update. here is the event log you asked for

Log Name:
Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          12/12/2011 11:57:52 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      HANU-LPT2.hanusoftware.local
Description:
Faulting application name: WebMatrix.exe, version: 7.1.1307.1, time stamp: 0x4e694933
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0xd8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccb8971a1262b8
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\WebMatrix.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 6a9b0c3e-248a-11e1-ab5c-705ab6a78e2c
Event Xml:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-12T06:27:52.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>418956</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>HANU-LPT2.hanusoftware.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>WebMatrix.exe</Data>
    <Data>7.1.1307.1</Data>
    <Data>4e694933</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7601.17651</Data>
    <Data>4e211319</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>0000b9bc</Data>
    <Data>d8</Data>
    <Data>01ccb8971a1262b8</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\WebMatrix.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6a9b0c3e-248a-11e1-ab5c-705ab6a78e2c</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Well that's not cool at all.  I'll pass this onto the devs, and make sure we figure out what's up.

Comment: Could you possibly paste the call stack from your event log?  Go to start, and type 'eventvwr'.  Choose 'windows logs', and double click on 'application'.  You should see a list of Info/Errors - if you find one that is an error and refers to WebMatrix.exe, please open that. Click the copy button, and paste it in a comment on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's well-known issue:

> there is a known issue with Dev 11 Beta and WM 2 Beta.  We are
>   actively working on an update to WM 2 Beta to address this - I
>   anticipate this will be released early next week (Chris Sfanos, Web
>   Platform Installer PM)

Recommendation to rollback:

1. Uninstall Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU CTP1
2. Uninstall Web Platform Installer
3. Uninstall WebMatrix Beta 2
4. Uninstall IIS 7.5 Express
5. (If you installed PHP for WebMatrix) Delete the remaining PHP folder under C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express
6. Install Web Platform Installer 3.0 (http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)
7. Install WebMatrix 1 from the Web Platform Installer 3.0
8. (If desired) Install PHP for WebMatrix from the Web Platform Installer 3.0

Link: http://forums.iis.net/p/1187677/2015970.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Webmatrix.

Go to Documents->IISExpress->config folder
Delete the applicationhost.config file and start webmatrix
It should start normally

found the solution on IIS forums

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with my applicationhost.config the bindings that I setup stopped working.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50499:*" />
```

Had to become, still unsure why

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50499:localhost" />
```